# AVPlayer streaming works and yet it doesn't

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

Running Xcode 7.1.1 under El Capitan 10.11.2 an IOS 9.2 app

Trying to understand the minimum code I need to implement playback for a Video stream, and crafted this very simply piece here ... don't need the Observer strictly speaking, but it crept in so I left it.

```
static const NSString *ItemStatusContext;
// a class static

self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"]];
[self.avPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&ItemStatusContext];

self.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(128, 128, 512, 386);
[self.view.layer addSublayer: avPlayerLayer];
[self.avPlayer play];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

if (context == &ItemStatusContext ) {
    AVPlayer *thePlayer = (AVPlayer *)object;
    if ([thePlayer status] == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
        NSError *error = [self.avPlayer error];
        // Respond to error: for example, display an alert sheet.
        NSLog(@"error %@",error);
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"player status %ld",(long)[thePlayer status]);
    // Deal with other status change if appropriate.
}
// Deal with other change notifications if appropriate.
//[super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object
 //                      change:change context:context];
return;
}
```

It works, but... only on the demo stream provided by Apple, nothing else I give it plays ...

** TRIED **

Tried adding this code into the mix too, which also works with the Apple demo stream, but none of the others I have tried.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];
AVURLAsset *avasset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];

avPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:avasset];
self.avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];
```

.......

** *MORE UPDATES* ** ... reworked observer since I wasn't getting useful info from it, now it tells me the Apple m3u8 is really to play; and "fails" on everything else I try...

So .... all these fail for example ...

```
 //self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://content.uplynk.com/209da4fef4b442f6b8a100d71a9f6a9a.m3u8"]];
//self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/vM7nH0Kl.m3u8"]];
//self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://walterebert.com/playground/video/hls/sintel-trailer.m3u8"]];

 - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {


if (object == self.avPlayer.currentItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {

    if (avPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
        NSError *error = [self.avPlayer error];
        // Respond to error: for example, display an alert sheet.
        NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusFailed error %@",error);
        return;
    }
    if (avPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerStatusUnknown) {
        NSError *error = [self.avPlayer error];
        NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusUnknown error %@",error);
    }
    if (avPlayer.currentItem.status  == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
        NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");
        [self.avPlayer play];
    }
    //[super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object
             //              change:change context:&ItemStatusContext];
    // Deal with other status change if appropriate.
}
// Deal with other change notifications if appropriate.
//[super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object
 //                      change:change context:context];

return;
```

}

Comment: Make sure the file path you're giving is correct.

Comment: Zachary, I have tried with some tutorial examples and youtube, none work. I am streaming, not downloading/playing from a file. That I have working.

Comment: Tried going thru an avasset too, that works with the Apple demo, but nothing else...

Comment: Updated observer code; now reporting accurately it seems, everything is un-streamable except the Apple demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew, recall something about this before; no excuses really. Managed to fix it by looking somewhere completely different; in info.plist which needs this key in it to play arbitrary streams.

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
 </dict>
```

I know it is bit lax, but I leave the reader to do so some more research if they want to make their app more bullet proof that I care about right now :) Do this, use the observer code in the **EDITED** section and cut out the *[self.avPlayer play]* (line 8) in the main code your be in business.

Comment: Warning: As of 2018, if you allow arbitrary loads then be prepared to explain Apple why with justifications. If the justifications aren't sufficient to them then your app is subject to rejection. In short, DO NOT, allow arbitrary loads, unless absolutely necessary.