# Play video in iOS from a URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation, http-live-streaming

I want to play a videos on iOS from a URL. I don't want to use `AVPlayerViewController` by the way.

I’m using `youtube-dl` for learning purposes. This gets me the raw url of a video on youtube such as:

> https://r3---sn-ab5l6nzk.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?upn=3VzVwzrmNT8&lmt=1471130096030949&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&mime=video%2Fmp4&itag=22&pl=27&ipbits=0&expire=1492204641&sparams=dur,ei,expire,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,ipbypass,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,upn&requiressl=yes&ei=AejwWMOXBIiD8wST6aK4CA&dur=663.394&key=cms1&ip=209.95.50.62&id=o-AAVxdc4Jw2onrtv50WYrfSHZNJAfNfmHE5otD3yIdGhU&signature=10A385D37D76E6695D4F49732B0BB3A0DA4F9700.4D0BB88220F8B24145A92AEB384E86432DB6FFC3&redirect_counter=1&req_id=50cca232f5fba3ee&cms_redirect=yes&ipbypass=yes&mm=31&mn=sn-ab5l6nzk&ms=au&mt=1492182931&mv=m

I want to learn how to play this on iOS. But I'm not sure if this url refers to:

- A file-based asset

OR

- An HTTP Live Stream

In the url above, I see there is a `Fmp4`, does this mean it’s an HTTP live stream?

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934886/avurlasset-cannot-load-with-remote-file), it states you can’t directly use an `AVURLAsset`. Based on `AVFoundation` guide, that seems to be correct. Please see where red arrow is pointing:

[image]

But this other [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/ExploringAVFoundation/ExploringAVFoundation.html) seems to contradict the above:
[image]

**Should I create an `AVURLAsset` directly or an `AVPlayerItem` directly?**

**If I create the `AVPlayerItem` directly, isn’t this synchronous and therefore will freeze the UI?**

Answer (score 1):

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:"your video url"];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
    AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
    playerViewController.player = player;
    [self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:^{
        [player play];
    }];
```

Comment: I don't plan on using `AVPlayerViewController ` because it abstracts away all of the details. How would you do this without `AVPlayerViewController `? Should I create an AVURLAsset directly or an AVPlayerItem directly?

Comment: After creating `AVPlayer` You can use `AVPlayerLayer` to play video without `AVPlayerViewController ` 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578839/avplayer-streaming-works-and-yet-it-doesnt